# How do I gather images from a website including any referenced in CSS files?

Tags: php, css, parsing, dom

Currently, I'm using Simple HTML DOM which works great for  tags:

```
    $html = file_get_html($url);
    $images = $html->find('img');
    $result = '';
    foreach ($images as $image):
        $result .= '<img src="'.$this->tasks->rel2abs($image->src, $url).'"><br>';
    endforeach;
    $html->clear(); 
    unset($html);
    echo $result;
```

But how would I also get images from CSS files, such as background: or background-image:?

Comment: Assuming you are using the same technique to pull down css files specified in `<meta>` tags and to get the text inside `<style>` tags, use a regular expression to get the contents of the `url()` syntax.. something like `url\(([^)]\)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). The following code is untested, but it should be pretty close to what you need.

First, you'll need to get all of the CSS blocks by using a search similar to yours above.

```
$css_inline = $html->find("style");
$css_external = $html->find("link[rel='stylesheet']");
```

...then you can search the inline blocks for `url()`:

```
$css_images = array();

function extract_css_images ( $css )
{
    global $css_images;

    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all( "/url\((.*?)\)/", $css, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

    foreach ( $matches as $match )
    {
        $css_images[] = trim( $match[1], "\"'" );
    }
}

foreach ($css_inline as $css)
{
    extract_css_images( $css->save() );
}
```

...then fetch the external css files and repeat:

```
foreach ($css_external as $css_file)
{
    $file = $css_file->href;
    $css = file_get_contents($file);        
    extract_css_images( $css );
}
```

`$css_images` should then be filled with image urls. It's a good idea to run `array_unique` to eliminate dupes, and you may have to prepend path information if they use relative paths.

Again, this is untested from memory, but it should get you close. This will not find any images that are inserted via Javascript. That would be a much trickier proposition.

Comment: Very very cool. I almost have it working, except when it looks for images in an external file, it just returns http://www.whatever.com/ as the image source, not the actual image name.

Comment: My code above uses global variables for the sake of keeping it short...`extract_css_images()` doesn't return anything, it just populates the global `$css_images` variable. So you'll want to run all of the code I provided above, then loop through `$css_images`, which will all be image urls (possibly relative paths). Even better, rewrite it to return the results rather than populating the global variable.